# Extract values from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, underscore.js, lodash

I have the below JSON string. The id-dashes in the file are not optional unfortunately, neither is the syntax. I would like to extract the "dd" values with JavaScript/Node.

```
{  
   "a-id":{  
      "b-id":"random",
      "bb-id":"random",
      "bbb-id":"random",
      "bbbb-id":{  
         "c":[  
            {  
               "d":"random",
               "dd":"This_info_is_needed"
            },
            {  
               "d":"random",
               "dd":"This_info_is_needed"
            },
            {  
               "d":"random",
               "dd":"This_info_is_needed"
            },
            {  
               "d":"random",
               "dd":"This_info_is_needed_2"
            }
         ]
      },
      "bbbbb-id":"random",
      "bbbbbb-id":"random"
   }
}
```

I would be open to use any additional helper like lodash, jQuery, etc.

The output should be an array with: This_info_is_needed and This_info_is_needed_2.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what kind out output do you want? what would it look like?

Comment: It doesn't really matter. In the end it would be great to have an array with unique values of the key "dd".

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom function that will search your data deep and return value if key is `dd` using `for...in` loop.

```js
var obj = {"a-id":{"b-id":"random","bb-id":"random","bbb-id":"random","bbbb-id":{"c":[{"d":"random","dd":"This_info_is_needed"},{"d":"random","dd":"This_info_is_needed"},{"d":"random","dd":"This_info_is_needed"},{"d":"random","dd":"This_info_is_needed"}]},"bbbbb-id":"random","bbbbbb-id":"random"}}

function getDD(data) {
  var result = []
  for(var i in data) {
    if(i == 'dd') result.push(data[i])
    if(typeof data[i] == 'object') result.push(...getDD(data[i]))
  }
  return result
}

console.log(getDD(obj))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just interested in the values only, can also just do this:

```js
var obj = {"a-id":{"b-id":"random","bb-id":"random","bbb-id":"random","bbbb-id":{"c":[{"d":"random","dd":"This_info_is_needed"},{"d":"random","dd":"This_info_is_needed"},{"d":"random","dd":"This_info_is_needed"},{"d":"random","dd":"This_info_is_needed"}]},"bbbbb-id":"random","bbbbbb-id":"random"}};

var desiredResults = obj['a-id']['bbbb-id']['c'].map(function(data){return data.dd});

console.log(desiredResults);
```